# Haskell parse error on input ‘<-’ Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and having a really hard time with this very simple program:

```hs
chooseDifficulty :: IO ()
chooseDifficulty =
    do putStrLn "Choose your difficulty:"
       putStrLn "  1: easy"
       putStrLn "  2: medium"
       putStrLn "  3: difficult"
       let choice <- getLine
       putStrLn "Choice was " ++ choice

main :: IO ()
main = chooseDifficulty
```

I'm having the error "parse error on input ‘<-’ Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?" on line 7. I've tried all sorts of formatting but haven't been able to fix that since it's in a do block already.

Comment: Remove `let`. You either use `<-` (in a `do`-block) or `let` (which is used with `=`). Both can be used in a `do` block, but you only use `<-` by itself or `let` with `=`. They have different meanings, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's `do` syntax has the following features:

#### 1.

```
   do
    ...
    action   -- e.g. putStrLn "bla"
    moreStuff
```

Simply executes the action (i.e. binding it into the monad), discards any results, and doesn't introduce new variables. Under the hood this uses the [`>>` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) to sequence `action` before everything that comes afterwards, `action >> moreStuff`.

#### 2.

```
   do
    ...
    let v = 37
    moreStuff
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with monadic actions, it's just a slightly different way of writing the standard `let`:

```
   do
    ...
    let v = 37 in moreStuff
```

or

```
   do
    ...
    let v = 37
     in do
      moreStuff
```

Note that this only works with “pure values” like numbers; it would be no use to write something like `let v = getLine` because this wouldn't actually invoke the action, only give a new name to it.

#### 3.

```
   do
    ...
    y <- resultfulAction   -- e.g. getLine
    moreStuff
```

No `let` in this one. This executes the action and binds its result in the variable `y`. Under the hood it uses the [`>>=` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-), namely `resultfulAction >>= \y -> moreStuff`.